# Excel xlsm file macro not showing

Tags: excel, vba, xlsm

I have a xlsm file that today I opened and i can't reach the macros in it.
[image]

Any idea what could have happened?

Answer (score 0):

I think i answered it rather quickly after searching here:
https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/1112769-corrupted-microsoft-excel-macro-enabled-workbook-xlsm-file.html

Answer (score 0):

If macros show in editor but not in the list (and security settings should be allowing), one quick fix is to record a new macro. The existing macros now appear in the list and you can delete the newly-created macro.